# Hyperlink to a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, hyperlink

I want to retrieve a hyperlink to a cell in Excel and then paste this hyperlink in a third party app.  Clicking the hyperlink should load Excel with the appropriate workbook and that cell should be selected with the cursor.

The hyperlink should work in Microsoft-related products like OneNote; for example, if I have a workbook "D:\abc.xls" and I want to jump to cell C12, I would make an hyperlink like "D:\abc.xls#C12".

And this would work; however, if I paste this in a non-Microsoft applicaltion it just opens up Excel and the workbook, but the cell isn't highlighted.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: As far as I know, no. OneNote does a lot of "funny" stuff. I am user of OneNote 2003 and 2007, and an Office developer since pre Office '95. To this day, OneNote still surprises me on some of the stuff it does. I believe OneNote is using "send-keys" to navigate to the specific cell. Excel maintains the "last-current-position" that it restores when opening a Workbook.

Comment: There may be VBA macros that provide this functionality because it is a common request.

Comment: @AMissico:I tried the same in "Word" too and it works there too! Regarding the macros I have done some googling around but haven't found similar functionality.

Comment: @Kevin Boyd: When I first noticed OneNote doing this, I used all my "tricks" to figure out how. I gave up after an hour because I had other stuff to do.

Comment: The HYPERLINK worksheet function does exactly what you want. Maybe a VBA macros take advantage of this.

Comment: I also just remembered, Excel supports DDE. Now that I think about it, I am sure the Office applications are using DDE, which allows for greater functionality.

Comment: @AMissico: With the HYPERLINK function how can I check the incoming hyperlink any leads? I mean when I click a hyperlink in another app will the HYPERLINK in excel detect the incoming event?

Comment: @Kevin Boyd: The problem is Excel does not support any command-line to do this. HYPERLINK only works within Excel. From my earlier review, Alex K is right in that the Office application are parsing the hyperlink, opening the document, then carrying out the "commands". In your example, navigating to C12. That is why I suspected "send-keys" and now DDE.

Comment: @AMissico - Thanks for your time!..I'm in the process of trying Alex's idea, in the meanwhile is there any roundabout solution to this? like going thru' another app or writing a helper app in VBA or VSTO? Are there any events on incoming hyperlinks in excel at the application level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE comment

That's what i was suggesting, for example save the following as a .reg and import it

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XLOPEN]
@="URL:Excel Opener"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XLOPEN\shell\open\command]
@="CSCRIPT.EXE \"C:\\TEMP\\XLOPEN.VBS\" \"%1\""
```

This makes an `XLOPEN://` URL protocol handler thatr when invoked will run XLOPEN.VBS.

Save the following as `C:\TEMP\XLOPEN.VBS`

```
rem //get an argument like "XLOPEN://C:\null\text.xlsx/#F55" note extra /
dim arg:  arg = WScript.Arguments.item(0)
dim arr:  arr = (split(ucase(arg), "#"))
rem unmangle the url
dim filename: filename = replace(arr(0), "XLOPEN://", "")
if (right(filename, 1) = "/") then filename = mid(filename, 1, len(filename)-1)
dim xl:   set xl = createobject("excel.application")
xl.Workbooks.Open filename 
xl.range(arr(1)).select
xl.visible = true
```

Now if you run

`xlopen://c:\null\test.xlsx#Q50`

or use

`<a href="xlopen://c:\null\test.xlsx#Q50">bla bla</a>`

Windows will lookup `xlopen://` and pass the string `xlopen://c:\null\test.xlsx/#Q50` to XLOPEN.VBS which extracts the file path `c:\null\test.xlsx1` and opens it, then selects the range after the #.

This works if called in browsers/from the shell/via the windows API, no idea if it will work in the 3rd party app. (You would replace the script with a helper exe)

Comment: Before your post, I tried doing some tests, like I opened internet explorer and pasted the link D:\abc.xls and it opened the file, however if I pasted the link D:\abc.xls#C12 it gives a error message. I thought if it works in word and onenote it should have worked in IE too, I wonder why it's not opening the cell. Thanks for the very elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This must be something automagically done by Office apps as the path: `abc.xls#C12` taken as a whole is a potentially valid filename itself - if you try to run it from the shell you'll get a "path not found" error.

If you click that link in onenote and look at the command line the resulting instance of excel was opened with there is only the "-embedding" switch which probably means onenote is parsing out `abc.xls`, launching excel via its automation features then activating `C12`.

I think if you want that functionality you would need to do the same thing using a helper app and use paths like "`C:\your_XL_loader.exe D:\abc.xls#C12`".

(If the 3rd party application honors windows protocol handers its trivial to make your_XL_loader.exe associate its self with something like `XXX://abc.xls#C12`)

Comment: the 3rd party app is a Java app and I don't know how to associate the _XL_loader.exe to associate to a hyperlink. Also the #C12 part of the hyperlink will change depending on what cell I want to highlight.

Comment: Its just a few registry settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx - but it relies on the java app being smart enough to either understand custom url protocol handlers or at least pass them off to the shell.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make sense of this, what is _XL_loader.exe? You see I have a java app that will initiate the url request, do you want me to make a helper app that we take this request and then pass it on to excel in a format that excel understands, is that right?